# Pull one element out of all the duplicates in an mongodb array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

[image: array]

This is my array in MongoDB:

cardOwners: Array
0: "9999"
1: "4444"
2: "4444"
3: "4444"

I want to ONLY pull and remove 1 of the "4444" elements in the array, but it pulls away all of them when I try it out.

Is there anything I can do to just remove 1 of the duplicate ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this approach

```
let result = await card.findOne({filter })
const index = result.cardOwners.findIndex(element => element === "4444");
result.cardOwners.splice(index, 1);
await result.save()
```