# How can I remove the first item that match a specific condidtion from an array in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have an entity like this in MongoDB

```
{
  "key": "8tlo14ab-BTzjR2oaigS1",
  "sessionName": "sessionNameTest1",
  "votes": ['userid1', 'userid1', 'userid2'],
}
```

So whenever someone wants to vote, I'll push the `userId` to the `votes` array. Each user can vote multiple times.
And when they want to downvote, I'll remove their id from `votes` array, just remove 1 id element.

The problem is `$pull` and `$pullAll` operators in MongoDB will remove every element that matches a specific condition.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you have two same ids in the votes array

Comment: Is this question related with yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66181997/pull-one-element-out-of-all-the-duplicates-in-an-mongodb-array ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pull one element out of all the duplicates in an mongodb array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66181997/pull-one-element-out-of-all-the-duplicates-in-an-mongodb-array)

Answer (score 0):

I assume the order of elements does not matter. In this case you can do it like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         votes: {
            $concatArrays: [
               {
                  $slice: [
                     { $filter: { input: "$votes", cond: { $eq: ["$$this", "userid1"] } } },
                     1,
                     { $size: "$votes" }
                  ]
               },
               { $filter: { input: "$votes", cond: { $ne: ["$$this", "userid1"] } } }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f6V7PmK_aSR)

Another solution could be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         votes: {
            $reduce: {
               input: { $range: [0, { $size: "$votes" }] },
               initialValue: [],
               in: {
                  $cond: {
                     if: { $eq: ["$$this", { $indexOfArray: ["$votes", 'userid1'] }] },
                     then: "$$value",
                     else: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$votes", "$$this" ] }]] }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```